# Using pika in asynchronous mode, how do I get the name of a server-named queue?

Tags: python, pika

I'm following the [asynchronous consumer example](https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html), and I want to declare a server-named queue as follows:

```
channel.queue_declare(on_queue_declareok, '')
```

My callback looks like this:

```
def on_queue_declareok(frame):
    queue_name = ????    # What goes here?
    channel.queue_bind(on_bindok, queue_name, EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY)
```

How do I get the server-generated name from the `frame` parameter. If I print it out, it looks like this:

```
<METHOD(['frame_type=1', 'channel_number=1',
    "method=<Queue.DeclareOk(['queue=amq.gen-NqdbEFHZdrtC4iLNdJpbjQ',
        'message_count=0', 'consumer_count=0'])>"])>
```

The queue name is in there. What is this thing? How do I get the queue name out?

Comment: `frame.method.queue` ???

Comment: @Vor make this the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a unique name using `frame.method.queue`.